# python conda - created a new environment, but it still used python in base environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I recently found this problem, but I don't remember that this problem happened before:

If I created a new environment called `test`, installed python and package that is not pre-installed in base environment, for example, `netCDF`:

```
(base) $ conda create -n test  
(base) $ source activate test
(test) $ conda install python
(test) $ conda install -c conda-forge netcdf4
```

But in command line, it seems like it still used python of base environment:

```
(test) $ which python
/mypath/anaconda3/bin/python
```

So in python shell, it failed to import `netcdf`:

```py
(test) $ python
>>> import netCDF4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'
```

But in my IDE (for example, jupyter notebook), it works well. It successfully using python in `test` environment because it can import `netCDF` without any problem:

```py
[1] import netCDF4   (in jupyter, it is imported successfully)
```

Why this situation happened? Why I was in `test` environment but it still using python of `base` environment?

Any suggestiion is helpful. Very thanks!

Comment: What about `conda create -n test python=3.6` or even `conda create -n test python=3.6 anaconda` to install Python along with the new env?

Comment: @S3DEV Thank you, but it still failed...

Comment: does the following return anything? : (test) $ which python3

Comment: @BastienHarkins It still return the same result. Results of `(test) $ which python`, `(test) $ which python3`, and `(base) $ which python` are identical.

Comment: What to the environment variables look like before and after the activation?  (Just redirect the before/after output to a file and diff the files)

Comment: @S3DEV This result is too long so I paste the result here: http://codepad.org/iyBz2zWR      (here my activate env is called `as2`)

Comment: This sometimes happens when the management of the `PATH` and/or `CONDA_*` environment variables by Conda gets desynchronized. Did you try starting a fresh shell? Or possibly run `conda deactivate` until no longer activated, then do `conda activate test`. Also, note that `source activate test` is a deprecated syntax; the current syntax is `conda activate test`.

Comment: @merv I have tried starting a fresh shell, also have tried to re-activate environment, but the problem is not solved.  I can only use `source activate test` because the conda version in my machine is old, it's 4.3.21.

Comment: @Chun-YeLu Just had a look at the env variables output you provided. You need to figure out why this: `/Dellwork4/cwullu/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/.bin:/Dellwork4/cwullu/anaconda3/bin:` is prepended to PATH after the `source activate as2` call. Once you identify the cause, then figure out how to prevent it. Any chance you're in a `tmux` session? I vaguely recall some `tmux` users having this happen to them, but that had a specific fix.

Comment: @merv Very thanks for your help!  I still don't find out the reason why the wrong path is prepended to PATH after `source activate as2`. My alternative solution (but brutal) is to create a script `reset_python_path.sh` in `/Dellwork4/cwullu/anaconda3/envs/as2/etc/conda/activate.d` to reset the python path to the correct one, and also recover to the origin setting in `deactivate.d`. It is a dirty solution, but at least it can work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ conda create --name test python=3.7
$ conda activate test
$ which python
```

> Output: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/test/bin/python